Functionally achieve --ffunction-sections from assembly
I'm linking against a static library that I don't have the original source code to, and it's absolutely critical that I produce the smallest binary.  Although unused .text sections from this library get stripped, if (e.g.) there's a .o containing even a single function that my code uses, then the entire .text section of that object gets linked into the final executable. Is there a way to link more selectively?
I tested with a C source file and its corresponding assembly (generated via gcc -S test.c):
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int num)
{
    return num * 2;
}

void main()
{
    int res = foo(5);
    printf("%d", res);
}

Running gcc --ffunction-sections -c test.c results in an object file with two different sections for main and foo, which is my desired result. This way, I can link with --gc-sections and only link the functions I actually use.
Running gcc -S test.c; gcc -c --ffunction-sections test.s however, results in an object file with one single .text section for both main and foo. If I link against this (e.g., with the intent of only using foo), the final executable will still contain the function main, even though I & foo do not use main. This doesn't really surprise me, but is there a way to functionally achieve having each function in their own section when I only have the disassembly (assembly) available to me?
I investigating objcopy with various flags, but it seems that tool is rather limited. I'd rather avoid a lethargic manual process if possible.

Edit the question to provide a [mre].

It's not just the functions your code calls and the external objects it accesses that need to be linked.  The functions that those functions call and the objects that those functions access, both external and internal, need to be linked too.  And so on.

I'm uncertain what you mean by "a way to functionally achieve this".  If you're asking about expressing your intent in your C source code then the C language does not specify anything appropos, and I'm not aware of any GCC extensions that would elicit the behavior you describe with respect to the already-built static library in question.

Possibly you could unpack the object files from your library, decompile them, then recompile with -ffunction-sections and build a new library from the rebuilt objects.  I imagine you could even script that.  But to the best of my knowledge, the linker and most other tools that work with object files don't know how to decompose a section.  Sections are atomic to those tools.

@EricPostpischil: There's plenty here. I can answer as is. OP may not like the answer, but that's a different problem.
